# Get the selected items inside a List Box and assign them to a SharePoint text field Defult property

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, powerapp, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas

I have a ListBox inside my Power Apps screen, as follow:

[image]

And I have a hidden text box, where I want to define the Default value for the text box to be the selected items (if any) from the ListBox separated by ",".

So from the above screen the Default value for the text box should be "Wireless Mouse/Keyboard", while if the user select all the values inside the List Box, then the Default value for the textbox should be "Docking Station, Wireless Mouse/Keyboard, Monitors ".

Any advice on this please?

Answer (score 0):

Use below formula in **Default** property of text box control:

```
Left(
    Concat(
        ListBox1.SelectedItems,
        Value & ", "
    ),
    Len(
        Concat(
            ListBox1.SelectedItems,
            Value & ", "
        )
    ) - 1
)
```

Where `ListBox1` is the name of ListBox control.

**Output**:

[image]